# Writing a pyproject.toml file to build submodules for independent import

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to write a pyproject.toml file for my project that contains a couple submodules (note: I did NOT get the final say in this structure) and I'd like to independently build the submodules.

The structure of my project is:

```
project/
   pyproject.toml
   src_dir/
      module1_dir/
         module1_file1.py
         module1_file2.py
         mod1_tests_dir/
      module2_dir/
```

And in `module1_file2.py` I have an import that looks like `from module1_dir.module1_file1 import var`. This works no problem in the unit tests. But in a functional test `python module1_file2.py` I get an error that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1_dir'`.

I'd like to write a pyproject.toml file that allows me to build `module1` and `module2` independently so that I can import from each of them in the style mentioned above.

Right now I have

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
 
[project]
name = "project"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [{name="Me", email="me@me.com"}]
requires-python = ">=3.11"
 
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src_dir/module1_dir"]
include = ["module1_dir"]
 
[tool.poetry]
packages = [
    { include = "module1_dir" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

if i must guess i would say the problem is your "where" argument, that points inside the package, so module1_dir.module_fileX cannot be found, only module_fileX can. Change it to where = ["src_dir"] and it should work.